# What is the usecase of DirectorySeparatorChar in .Net

Tags: .net, windows, unix, use-case

In the Namespace `System.IO` from `mscorlib.dll` there is the following field:

```
public static readonly char DirectorySeparatorChar
```

According to the documentation, it contains `\` on Windows and `/` on Unix. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My Question: Why is this field here? What is the usecase of it?

My assumption was always, that .NET is only supported on the Windows Platform.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some .Net Code (Not all) can be run on Linux Platforms as well using Mono.

A commonly used code block across windows and Linux would be the primary use case for the field in question.

Please take a look [at the project documentation from mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications)  and search for DirectorySeperatorChar or scroll down to it!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this field here?

To not tie an application to Windows, or rather the `\` separator.

> What is the usecase of it?

See above.

> My assumption was always, that .NET is only supported on the Windows Platform.

The Microsoft .NET Framework is only *supported* on Windows, yes. The team at some point decided they do want to encourage other implementations of the CLI, possibly running on other operating systems, and adding fields like this only helps that.